# Insert a vector into a specific cell of data frame in R

Tags: r

I have a small situation in R.

I have a dataframe as below:

```
                 age
numCategories      9
signFeatures      NA
nullDeviance      NA
residualDeviance  NA
aic               NA
```

I want to insert a vector as c(1,2,3) in a particular cell of the data frame.

For example my data frame after replacement should look somethinglike:

```
                  age
numCategories      9
signFeatures      c(1,2,3)
nullDeviance      NA
residualDeviance  NA
aic               NA
```

I tried doing the below:

```
df['signFeatures', 'age'] <- c(1,2,3) &
df['signFeatures', 'age'] <- Vectorize(c(1,2,3))
```

Both the time it gives me the same error:

```
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "signFeatures", "age", value = c(1,  :
```

replacement has 3 rows, data has 1

I understand the problem, but cant find a way to solve it.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I believe a `data.frame()` can not contain more than 1 value. Maybe you should handle this with `lists`

Comment: This can be done, but is not recommended.  Each column of a df has to have the same class, so if you change the class of `df$age` from `numeric` to `list`, you can then put whatever you like in it, although it might not behave as expected!  So `class(df$age) <- "list"` then `df$age[2] <- c(1,2,3)`.

Comment: Often, if you want to do this, it's a sign you aren't thinking about your data right. Here, looking at your data frame, it seems as if your cases are in your columns and your variables are in rows.

Answer (score 3):

Like Andrew mentioned above, each column of a data frame has to have to same class, so you can record, instead, a transposed version of your desired table above:

```
data <- data.frame(numCategories = 9)
data$signFeatures <- list(c(1,2,3))
data$nullDeviance <- rnorm(1)
data$residualDeviance <- rnorm(1)
data$aic <- rnorm(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I do not know if it is possible with data frames, but is possible with [Tibbles](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/tibbles.html).

Here is an approach using [mutate()](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/mutate.html) and [case_when()](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/case_when.html):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df = tibble(Type = c("numCategories", "signFeatures", "nullDeviance", "residualDevian","aic"),
           age = NA
            ) %>% mutate(age =  case_when(Type == "numCategories" ~ list(9),
                                          Type == "signFeatures" ~ list(c(1,2,3))
                                          )
                         )
```

You can print the results individually as follow:

```
df[2,"age"][[1]] %>% unlist()
## [1] 1 2 3
```